# Could not parse for environment production: no 'environments'

Tags: centos, puppet, theforeman

I have already installed puppet-server 3.7.5 and foreman. But when I am running this command I am getting below error.

```
~]# foreman-installer --foreman-db-type mysql

Error: 
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/context.rb:54:in `lookup': Could not parse for environment production: no 'environments' in {:root_environment=>#<Puppet::Node::Environment:0x7fe3646d9620 @modulepath=[], @watching=true, @config_version=nil, @manifest=:no_manifest, @name=:"*root*">, :current_environment=>#<Puppet::Node::Environment:0x7fe3646d9620 @modulepath=[], @watching=true, @config_version=nil, @manifest=:no_manifest, @name=:"*root*">} at top of [[0, nil, nil]] (Puppet::Error)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:236:in `lookup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:264:in `future_parser?'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/parser_factory.rb:12:in `parser'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/node/environment.rb:541:in `perform_initial_import'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/node/environment.rb:276:in `known_resource_types'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/resource/type_collection_helper.rb:5:in `known_resource_types'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/parser_support.rb:120:in `import'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo_parsers-0.0.3/lib/kafo_parsers/puppet_module_parser.rb:38:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo_parsers-0.0.3/lib/kafo_parsers/puppet_module_parser.rb:16:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo_parsers-0.0.3/lib/kafo_parsers/puppet_module_parser.rb:16:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/puppet_module.rb:44:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/configuration.rb:84:in `modules'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/configuration.rb:84:in `map'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/configuration.rb:84:in `modules'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/kafo_configure.rb:170:in `modules'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/kafo_configure.rb:152:in `params'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/kafo_configure.rb:185:in `set_parameters'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/kafo_configure.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/clamp-0.6.2/lib/clamp/command.rb:126:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/clamp-0.6.2/lib/clamp/command.rb:126:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kafo-0.6.5/lib/kafo/kafo_configure.rb:116:in `run'
    from /usr/sbin/foreman-installer:58
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug introduced due to some changes in the way environments work in Puppet 3.7 and is not compatible with previous version. Based on bug filed [here](http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/9916) you will need to supply arguments to foreman installer.